# Retrieving specific data element from the returned array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-retrieval

Here is my returned array:
`>0: RectangularNode {children: Array(0), position: {…}, size: {…}, strokeWidth: 0, selected: true, …}`  [Directly captured from the browser]

When expanded above array I have:
`>0: RectangularNode args: {radiusBottomLeft: 5, radiusTopLeft: 5, radiusTopRight: 5, radiusBottomRight: 5} canConnect: (routable, role) => {…} children: [] direction: "XX" features: Set(10) {…} hoverFeedback: true id: "_1234HGGD554" isContainableElement: element => {…} **name: "wstchieve"** opacity: 1 parent: GLSPGraph {children: Array(2), canvasBounds: {…}, scroll: {…}, zoom: 1, position: {…}, …} position: {x: 370, y: 130} selected: true size: {width: 128, height: 128} strokeWidth: 0 type: "signal" anchorKind: (...) bounds: (...) incomingEdges: (...) index: (...) outgoingEdges: (...) root: (...) [[Prototype]]: SNode`

Here my requirement is to fetch only the name property inside of the array object and store it in the variable.

Please suggest how can I achieve this in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Loop your array and try

```
for (var index = 0; index < yourarray.length; index++) {
    console.log("name=" + yourarray[index].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice to have some code to actually look at I'm not fully understanding your question. But i guess you just need to find the index you need? maybe something like this ?

```js
var oObject = {} ;
oObject["aaa"] = "AAA" ;
oObject["bbb"] = "BBB" ;
oObject["ccc"] = "CCC" ;
oObject["ddd"] = "DDD" ;
oObject["eee"] = "EEE" ;

var strName, strValue ;

for(strName in oObject)
{
   strValue = oObject[strName] ;
   alert("name : " + strName + " : value : " + strValue) ;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.keys(responseData)` if you need only object property .
if you need both keys and values use `Object.entries(responseData)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).